# Div next to canvas in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im making a shoe customizer and im trying to place my canvas (in three.js) next to a div. However, it doesnt work. I tried making the width of the renderer viewport smaller, which was a quick solution but it made my object compressed and it also wasn't responsive. Here is all the relevant code:

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="canvas-container"></div>
        <div class="customizer-container">
          // all of the code for the customisation of the shoe
      </div>
```

css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.canvas-container {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

.customizer-container{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 500px; 
  height:100vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

main.js

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');
canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: maybe you should `renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);` instead of relating to `window` dimensions?

Comment: @ITgoldman is correct. Using the window dimensions will set the render target to the wise of the window, not your container. You will need to get the computed width and height of your container to send to `renderer.setSize`, and if your webpage is reactive, you should react to any resizing as well, by using a `ResizeObserver`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, im trying to do this, but the width and height dissapear when i set it to the width of the canvas and height

Answer (score 0):

Removed height: 100vh; from body, removed position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); from customizer-container, Added position: relative; to canvas-container, use media query for responsive design as it's the common practice:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="canvas-container"></div>
  <div class="customizer-container">
    <!-- all of the code for the customization of the shoe -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.canvas-container {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative; /* Added */
}

.customizer-container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px; /* Adjust margin as needed */
}

/* Optional: Add media query for responsive design */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .customizer-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0; /* Adjust margin as needed */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but right now, the canvas is on top of the customizer, i would want them to be next to eachother

Comment: They're next to each other. They only stack on each other on the mobile screen and that's the point to make it responsive. Visit this fiddle with a desktop and you'll see them next to each other: https://jsfiddle.net/r71gqtLo/

Comment: This isn't the case for me, if you would want to look at my code and see if you can figure out what the problem is, i would highly appreciate it! 

https://github.com/milanaismail/sneaker